# Data visualization on Grafana dashboard

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana

I have an application that runs on Kubernetes to measure storage performance. Upon completion of each POD, it displays statistics in terms of IOPS, Bandwidth, and Latency.

Now, the requirement is to run the application daily and view the statistics on a Grafana dashboard. Can we send the data directly to Prometheus and view it on Grafana, or do we need any kind of database as a data source? Please assist me with this.

Please find the sample data here.

```
RANDOM_IOPS_READ,RANDOM_IOPS_WRITE,MIX_IOPS_READ,MIX_IOPS_WRITE,RANDOM_BW_READ,RANDOM_BW_WRITE,SEQUENSE_BW_READ,SEQUENCE_BW_WRITE,AVG_LATENCY_READ,AVG_LATENCY_WRITE
[67400.0, 8118.0, 1864.5, 613.5, 263.0, 31.8, 258.0, 0.93, 1.899, 15.782]
[82097.0, 9332.5, 1572.0, 527.0, 321.5, 37.25, 830.5, 5.721, 31.165, 271.93]
[78677.5, 8393.5, 1460.0, 476.5, 309.0, 33.9, 812.5, 7.262, 64.902, 606.7]
```

I'm not sure how to achieve this.

Comment: Prometheus **is** a database. But if you want to store and process only these metrics, and only for end of the application, Prometheus probably is not the wisest choice. Consider something push-based.